# Ambiguous tag: [mantle]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

As you can see in the whopping 5-post [history of the `mantle` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mantle), it can refer to both:

- Low-level graphics API by AMD
- Model framework for Cocoa and Cocoa Touch

Should they be divided? Should either have the priority?

Comment: Given that the graphics API questions seem to have come first, and the impact it is likely to have, I'd personally keep it associated with the graphics API.

Comment: @Bart That would be my opinion too, but since I'm clearly more involved in one of the subjects, it might be biased.

Comment: Same here I guess.

Comment: @Bart Mantle API by AMD seems to be phased out already: ["The Mantle SDK also remains available to partners who register in this co-development and evaluation program. However, if you are a developer interested in Mantle "1.0" functionality, we suggest that you focus your attention on DirectX® 12 or GLnext."](http://community.amd.com/community/amd-blogs/amd-gaming/blog/2015/03/02/on-apis-and-the-future-of-mantle)

Comment: Then Mantle intended as SDK should be removed and the description should be updated to the cocoa framework